# Parity Measurement Using a Single c-Z gate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I have a system with some number of qubits. To make it simple, but non-trivial, let's say that number is 3. I want to know the parity of the system's state (meaning I can assume that each individual qubit is either $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$). In particular, I should do this using a single application of a c-$Z^{\otimes n}$ gate (where in this case $n=3$ and the 'c-' prefix indicates that the gate is 'controlled'). I've looked it up, and the solution appears to be something like this:

[image: parity measurement]

I've seen some parity implementations using cascading `CNOT` gates on a static $|0\rangle$ input, and that makes perfect sense to me. As you can see by the '?'s in this image, though, I don't get what this circuit is doing at all. The measurement seems to only apply to the bottom wire, but how could this ever output anything but a measurement of $H|+\rangle=|0\rangle$ or $0$ 100% of the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two key facts you need here: $H \cdot Z \cdot H = X$ and $C \otimes Z = Z \otimes C$. (Also, you should look up the concept of "phase kickback".)

1. Start with [a trivial parity circuit](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Measure%22%5D%5D%7D):

[image: trivial parity circuit]

2. Use $H \cdot Z \cdot H = X$ to [replace those X gates with Z gates](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C1%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%2C%22Z%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Measure%22%5D%5D%7D).

[image: Z-ified parity circuit]

3. Use $C \otimes Z = Z \otimes C$ to [flip the direction of control](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22Z%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Z%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Measure%22%5D%5D%7D):

[image: rev-z'ed parity circuit]

4. The operations have a common control, so [shove 'em together](http://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22Z%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22Z%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Measure%22%5D%5D%7D):

[image: Single-column parity circuit]

5. You're done. You can replace the three small Z boxes with a single big $Z^{\otimes 3}$ box, but that's just decoration.

At first this kind of stuff seems weird, but as you [start thinking of controls and operations as interchangeable](http://algassert.com/post/1706) it becomes natural. And the pattern "control the operation $U$ with $HCH$ to measure the observable $U$ (if $U$'s eigenvalues are all +1 and -1)" is quite common. In this case $U = Z^{\otimes 3}$.

Comment: So I never really got around to writing my own answer, but I'd be happy to accept yours. There's just one thing I think should be clarified. A lot of the issues I was having stemmed from not understanding that the target gate could affect the control gate; I was thinking of the controls classically. Now that I understand phase kickback I understand how that circuit works, but that last line "how could this ever output anything but $0$?" demonstrates a lack of understanding entanglement through controlled gates.